# use stored procedure before representing fields in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-2010

I want to remove HTML tags before representing in report viewer in ASP.NET,
So I create the strip html function in sql server and call that inside a procedure as shown in the code below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE removeHTMLtags
@report_description NVARCHAR(MAX) 
  AS   
  BEGIN
    select dbo.stripHTML(@report_description);      
  END
```

My database field name is the same as my input parameter name.
Then I add this procedure into my crystal report when I add my tables.
I drag and drop the report_description field from the `removeHTMLtags` procedure to my report designer, and in the prompt section, I set the `report_description` field to null, but when I shift to report preview, nothing happens.

How can I solve this problem, and call my procedure before my field displays in the report viewer?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Crystal is this clever to be honest.

I would probably create a view which essentially adds the report_description_stripped column to the original table. Then just add the view to your report instead of the original table.

L

Answer (score 0):

@report_description is the parameter which needs your HTML.  You said when you Preview the report in Crystal Reports, you are setting @report_description to null, which means you are passing in nothing for your stored procedure to process and this is the reason you don't see anything on the report.  In order for your report to work, you need to pass in some HTML when Crystal prompts you to fill out @report_description.

In conclusion, to begin solving your problem, when you preview your report in crystal, copy/paste some HTML into the field for your parameter.